# Display binary vtk file in ascii format

Tags: linux, vim, binary, ascii, vtk

I have a program which writes the output as binary vtk file. Being a binary file, I am not able to understand it. However, I would like to read the contents of the file for my own understanding.  Is there a way to view it in ascii format (so that I could understand the data better)?

Comment: Try the python code in the mail archive http://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtkusers/2004-September/076136.html. And if that works you can create a filter so vim can read it directly into the buffer.

Comment: Receiving the following error: NameError: name 'vtkDataSetReader' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

A hex-editor or dumper will let you view the contents of the file, but it will likely still be unreadable. As a binary file, its contents are meant to be interpreted by your machine / vtk, and will be nonsensical without knowing the vtk format specifications.

Common hex dumpers include `xxd`, `od`, or `hexdump`.